# Can I make a client/server Task Manager using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client, taskmanager

My current project is to make an open source web-based KBTM (Knowledge Base Task Manager) for a large company. This company has an Active Directory database where it has all of its employees' usernames and passwords. My task manager has to connect to this database because the user has to log in with his credentials to use my application. Depending on the user's rank within the company, the application will have more or less features.

Can I make this KBTM using only JavaScript? I heard of Node.js for using JavaScrip on the server side. Is this viable? Or is there a better way of doing this that is open source?

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

NodeJs is one option to write a server backend, and in my opinion it is a great one if you like javascript.

With node you can easily fullfill your requirements.

Here a some articles why to choose node:
[link1](http://blog.modulus.io/top-10-reasons-to-use-node)
[link2](http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/node-js-becoming-go-technology-enterprise/)

Additionally, NodeJs comes with a great package manager called [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

With npm you can easily install millions of open source packages that can save you a lot of time.